# Magento2: Custom Graphql return "Cannot query field \"testSharingData\" on type \"Query\"

Tags: magento2, graphql

I create custom graphql and have a error,please help me.

```
type Query {
    testSharingData (
        id: Int @doc(description: "The ID of the CMS page.")
    ): TestSharingData @resolver(class: "GlobalBq\\SharingGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\SharingItem") @doc(description: "Return details about a CMS page.")
}

type TestSharingData @doc(description: "SharingData defines the customer name and other details"){
    customer_id: Int
}
```

---

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace GlobalBq\SharingGraphQl\Model\Resolver;
use GlobalBq\SharingGraphQl\Model\ResourceModel\Sharing\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;

class SharingItem implements \Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    private Collection $collection;

    /**
     * @param Collection $collection
     */
    public function __construct(Collection $collection)
    {
        $this->collection = $collection;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
    {

        $postData = [
            "customer_id" => 31
        ];
        return $postData;

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Try this**

```
{
  testSharingData(id: [YOURID] ) {
    customer_id
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry ,my picture is wrong. My request just like this.

Comment: Please run upgrade and cache command and check it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I only run setup:di:compile and clean cache, not run upgrade. it work for me.